# r software - identify objects in table column, more than, or less than

Tags: r, outliers

I will try to explain well my doubt.

I have a table with some variables X, Y, Z, for example.
Each variable has numeric values.

So, let's say I have

```
  RDIST   RDENS    AGR   BLF
1   146    0.000     0   0.0
2   338    0.000     0   0.0
3   931    0.000     0   3.7
```

I'm trying to identify outliers, so I used dotchart.

But now, I want to know, in each variable, in which observation I have the outliers.

With `list(x$BLF>3)` command, I get a table with `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. But what I need to know is if the outlier is in observation 2, 3, or 145.

Comment: Do you want the row index of the outlines? Use `which(x$BLF>3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @MrFlick. `which()` is the best way to go. If you want to take the next step and remove those outliers you could do
    `x$BLF<-x$BLF[-which(x$BLF>3)]` which takes those indexes MrFlick was talking about and deletes those entries from the BLF column, using the `-` operator. Of course after that you store it back to the same column. Actually, REALLY don't do what I said above because if your data is stored in a dataframe R will automatically replace the removed values with the value just above it to maintain the right column length!

Probably best to replace the outliers with NA like this `x$BLF[which(x$BLF>3)]<-NA`. Or you could just remove the entire row from your dataset like this `x<-x[-which(x$BLF>3),]` The reason you have the comma now is that when your dealing with a rectangular dataframe you have to specify row, column, like this `[row I want, column I want]` so I just specify the row I want deleted without specifying the column.

Probably more than you wanted, but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

That's it! Thank you both!

For now, I just want to identify the outliers for each variable. That command solved my doubt, tottaly.

Thank you